# How to remove or edit title bar when nativescript app runs on android platform

Tags: android, nativescript

i've tried in every way to call the requestWindowFeature method, first inside a page script (but raised a very nice error), second on app js, working inside application.launchEvent closure:

```
    var application = require("application");
    application.mainModule = "main-page";
    application.cssFile = "./app.css";

    application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
        if (args.android) {
        // How to work with android activity in this closure? 
        } 
    });
```

application.start();

I was not able to get an android activity instance in order to hide the default title bar.

Assuming that the "launchEvent" event it is assimilable to "onCreate" event, is there a way to get the android activity in this context? Or is necessary to assume that it isn't the proper way in order to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being you can try this:

```
application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
    if (application.android) {
        var activity = application.android.startActivity;
        // Do something with activity...
    } 
});
```

Our next release will include Android Activity Events. Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/374).